# Software audio to line in

Tags: audio

This may or may not be the place to ask, if not go ahead and toss it.

I've got a piece of software that's outputting audio which I would like to have routed to another piece of software. The easy solution is to hook up my headphone jack to my microphone jack or to enable stereo mixing on my computer. But, a further implementation of what I'm trying to do would have 2 instances of this happening on one machine. That means 2 pieces of software each broadcasting an audio signal, each individual stream should be able to be directed into its respective destination software.

My question is if anything exists that will do this.

Thanks!

EDIT: Dumb mistake, running Windows 7 (64-bit). The audio is coming out of SDR# and being processed in a piece of software to translate the APRS signal (haven't chosen that bit yet).

Comment: Please add information on what platform (Windows? Linux? Android?) you are using and what frameworks you are already using.

Comment: You might want to use something like [Virtual Audio Cable](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm).